# How to assign get value to a variable using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

How to assign value get from `first menu bar item of menu bar 1 whose description is "text input"` to another variable?

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SystemUIServer"
        get value of first menu bar item of menu bar 1 whose description is "text input"
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat `get value of ...` as the output and assign the value to the variable in a usual way. do not forget to place parentheses between `get value of ...`

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SystemUIServer"
        set inputValue to (get value of first menu bar item of menu bar 1 whose description is "text input")            

        return inputValue
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: The parentheses, in general, aren't required.  If they are needed, _Script Editor_ will usually insert them for you, which can be the case when using a `whose` filter.  You can also use the `get...` command on its own line (as you did when posting the question), then make the line that follows it `set inputValue to the result`.

Comment: Oh, and the other obvious solution that I neglected to mention is to simply remove the word `get`.  It's generally superfluous, and I can only think of one situation where it has a specific use, which is when you wish to evaluate a partially dereferenced list of items, such as _Finder_'s `selection`. So `tell app "Finder" to return item 1 of selection` will throw an error, but `tell app "Finder" to return item 1 of (get selection)` (where parentheses _are_ needed here), will dereference the `selection object` fully allowing `item 1` to be retrieved.